# Unable to determine the source of a gap in html/CSS; want it removed

Tags: html, css, formatting

https://www.ashenglowgaming.com

I don't really understand why the gap is there:

[image]

The browser's developer mode shows there is a void there:

```
<div class="scrhead">
...
</div>
<!-- end list games top bar -->
<!--THIS IS WHERE THE GAP APPEARS -->
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
```

Styling does not appear to be responsible because there is simply nothing there, not even any margin or padding that shows up from the element above `div.scrhead` or below `div#primary`.

Comment: How about your CSS? The common culprit in a case like this is usually something set to `display: inline-block`, which respects surrounding whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an css in your code because of this your gap is coming

```
#games-list-topbar{
  margin-bottom: 40px !important;
}
```

Try to reduce this value according to your requirement.

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing...  I didn't realise that, thank you...  Elementary mistake on my part...  Will accept your answer in a few minutes when I can. The margin highlight just didn't show up in the developer view...

Answer (score 1):

You can reset all the white space first using

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
 }
```

Comment: I tried; it made no difference?  What could this mean?

Comment: Where did you try it, order matters this means set all white space to none then override later with whatever comes